# Get Wikidata sitelinks counts for all items with at least one sitelink

Tags: wikidata

Is there a simple way to get the sitelinks count data for all Wikidata items?  I want to use the data to help rank possible text entity links to Wikidata items

I'm really only interested in counts for items that have at least one (e.g., wikibase:sitelinks value that's >0).  According to statistics I've seen, only about 1/3 of Wikidata items have at least one sitelink.

I'm not sure if wikibase:sitelinks is included in the standard WIkidata dump.  I could try a SPARQL query with an OFFSET and LIMIT, but I doubt that the approach would work to completion.

Answer (score 0):

Example query: "**Cats in Wikidata with most sitelinks**" here:

> ```
> # select all Cats, ordered by most Wikimedia sitelinks (with count and the raw sitelinks)
> SELECT ?item
>        ?itemLabel
>        ( COUNT( ?sitelink ) AS ?sitelink_count )
>        ( GROUP_CONCAT( ?sitelink ) AS $sitelinks_raw )
> WHERE {
>   ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146.        # it's a Cat
>   ?sitelink schema:about ?item. # sitelink about the item
>                                 # label in my language, or English
>   SERVICE wikibase:label {
>      bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
>   }
> }
> GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
> HAVING ( COUNT( ?sitelink ) > 3 )
> ORDER BY DESC( COUNT( ?sitelink ) )
> ```
>
> [Try query on Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20select%20all%20Cats%2C%20ordered%20by%20most%20Wikimedia%20sitelinks%20%28with%20count%20and%20the%20raw%20sitelinks%29%0ASELECT%20%3Fitem%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FitemLabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20COUNT%28%20%3Fsitelink%20%29%20AS%20%3Fsitelink_count%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20GROUP_CONCAT%28%20%3Fsitelink%20%29%20AS%20%24sitelinks_raw%20%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ146.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20it%27s%20a%20Cat%0A%20%20%3Fsitelink%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem.%20%23%20sitelink%20about%20the%20item%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20label%20in%20my%20language%2C%20or%20English%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0AHAVING%20%28%20COUNT%28%20%3Fsitelink%20%29%20%3E%203%20%29%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%20COUNT%28%20%3Fsitelink%20%29%20%29)

Is this interesting for you?

If you want, Wikidata has more nice examples about querying sitelinks in SPARQL here:

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#Working_with_sitelinks